# How to pass only 1 element to ArrayAdapter and make sure it only displays unique items

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, collections

Working on a project and have hit a mental wall trying to use a custom `ArrayAdapter` to display only unique elements from a class. I have a Class I've created that is simply made up of 3 strings. SongName, Category and Artist.

With that class I have created an `ArrayList` in my `MainActivity`. I would like to use that `ArrayList` in a few different activities. I've been able to use it in an `ArrayAdapter` that I created that displays all 3 fields in `TextViews` but I would like to create another `ArrayAdapter` for a different activity that only displays 1 of those fields and doesn't show the repeating items. So, for example, an `ArrayAdapter`  that is only provided Category element and only displays the unique ones.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to only pass 1 element from the `ArrayList` to `ArrayAdapter` and make sure it doesn't display duplicates.

Fairly new to the android development and haven't been able to find an answer to this, so would appreciate it if you could help me or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit Answer: was able to get it to work by adding this:

```
        ArrayList<Music> Library = MainActivity.music;


        ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

        Log.i("MainActivity", String.valueOf(Library.size()));
        for (int i = 0; i<Library.size(); i++){
            String artist = Library.get(i).getArtist();
            if (!artists.contains(artist))
            artists.add(artist);

            Log.i("MainActivity", "artist");
        }
```

Edit: including screenshot of the original ArrayList below. As you can see in my idea some of the categories and artists would repeat. I would like to create an activity that only displays the artists and another that only displays the categories. With the caveat being I only want the unique values to be displayed not duplicates & including github link.

github : https://github.com/Nimzr/Music-Player

[image: Arraylist music from the Music class]

Comment: It would be great if you could share some screenshots of what you are currently experiencing and also some related code.

Comment: Sounds to me that what you want is to simply get the one item in the list you want and throw within *another* `ArrayList` that can be then passed to the other ArrayAdapter.

Comment: @SyedAhmedJamil Good point, I added a screenshot but let me know what code you'd like me to include and I will.

Comment: @GabrielVasconcelos I was beginning to think the same. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `ArrayAdapter` will create views for each array item in your `ArrayList`. To customise how the `ArrayAdapter` create views for your data you need to extend it and override its `getView()` method and use a different layout for each item like this

***NOTE:*** Im assuming `Music` is that class which has those 3 strings and you have created a new layout called `unique_layout.xml` which has only one `TextView` to display one you those strings.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Music> {
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Music> musicList) {
       super(context, 0, users);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       Music music = getItem(position); 

       // Here use that new layout that you created 
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.unique_layout, parent, false);
       }

       // Assign text to the TextView from that new layout
       TextView category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category);
       category.setText(music.category);

       return convertView;
   }
}
```

**UPDATE: Remove Duplicates from ArrayList**

***NOTE:*** The following methods removes duplicates and put the resulting list in a new `ArrayList<String>` which you can use as source of your `ArrayAdapter`. So you don't have to extend `ArrayAdapter` now.

There are 3 common ways to remove duplicates from `ArrayList`

1. Do it manually *( good luck in that )*
2. Use `Streams` *( only available for API 24: Nougat and greater )*
3. Use `LinkedHashSet` *( available since API 1 )*

Lets say you have array list defined as follows

```
ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

musicList.add(new Music("song1", "category1", "artist1"));
musicList.add(new Music("song2", "category2", "artist2"));
musicList.add(new Music("song3", "category3", "artist3"));
musicList.add(new Music("song4", "category2", "artist4"));
musicList.add(new Music("song5", "category1", "artist1"));
musicList.add(new Music("song6", "category4", "artist5"));
musicList.add(new Music("song7", "category3", "artist2"));
```

**Option 2 : Using `Streams`**

What I'm doing here is that I'm extracting only the `category` field using the `map()` method and removing duplicates using the `distinct()` method then finally  collecting all this modification in `categoryList`. If you need to extract unique artist, just change `music.category` to `music.artist`

EZ !

***NOTE:*** After the `map()` method we are now dealing with array of strings so `distinct()` uses the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of the `String` class to find and remove duplicates. If you are using `distinct()` directly on your `musicList` which is an array of `Music` class then your `Music` class should override and provide implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Read more about them [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts) or [here](https://www.journaldev.com/21095/java-equals-hashcode)

```
categoryList = musicList.stream()
              .map((music)-> music.category)
              .distinct()
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

Log.d("CATEGORY LIST" ,  categoryList.toString())

//LOG Output 
CATEGORY LIST: [category1, category2, category3, category4]
```

**Option 3 : Using `LinkedHashSet`**

This method is rather simple. As before first extracting `category` fields and storing them into `categoryList`. Creating `LinkedHashSet` will automatically remove duplicate values just like the `distinct()` method did when using streams. Afterwards just clearing the `categoryList` and updating it with unique values from the hash set.

```
musicList.forEach((music) -> {
    categoryList.add(music.category);
});

LinkedHashSet<String> uniqueCategoryHashSet = new LinkedHashSet(categoryList);

categoryList.clear();
categoryList.addAll(uniqueCategoryHashSet);

Log.d("CATEGORY LIST" ,  categoryList.toString())

//LOG Output 
CATEGORY LIST: [category1, category2, category3, category4]
```

Now by no means I would mark **Option 3** as an efficient solution. Maybe you can do better doing it manually if you can't use streams due to API restriction. But this gets the job done.

Comment: This makes sense to me but it would still display duplicates if the ArrayList includes categories that repeat wouldn't it?

Comment: Well in that case the quick solution is to create a temporary new `ArrayList` from your current `ArrayList` using `streams` and remove entries that have same category (or whatever field you are focusing) and pass it to your custom array adapter. Streams are a java 8 concept so make sure your android studio is using java 8 and not java 7. I'll put a proper solution in a moment meanwhile you can see @Macro R answer which also uses streams

Comment: I got it by adding this, I was banging my head against the wall trying to understand streams which make sense but trying to see how I can work it was difficult. Let me know if how I approached is a bad idea. `
        ArrayList<Music> Library = MainActivity.music;


        ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i<Library.size(); i++){
            String artist = Library.get(i).getArtist();
            if (!artists.contains(artist))
            artists.add(artist);
        }` not sure what I can't get the `code` thing to work for the code above.

Comment: It was hard reading your code in the comments :) but yes your approach is pretty normal. What do you mean by  **"can't get the `code` thing to work"** ? Which code are you talking about ? Anyways sorry for late answer but I have updated my answer with different solutions on how you can remove duplicates. Do check it. Hope this answers your question

Comment: oh you have nothing to be sorry for, when I said I couldn't get the code thing to work I meant that the code block wasn't displaying properly in the comment. That's all. You were a huge help! thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I see. I'm glad I could help :). Also do mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem so others can take benefit from it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could start by creating a *trimmed version* of the object you want to view and then create a method utility that allows you to filter out the elements of your original `List` according to a parametrized condition. The elements left standing you map them to the new *trim* version and use that new `List` as the source for your custom `ArrayAdapter`. The following is a skeleton of this idea:

```
    public ArrayAdapter<TrimmedElement> createCustomArrayAdapter(
            Context context, List<WholeElement> target, Predicate<WholeElement> condition) {
        
        List<TrimmedElement> trimmedList = target.stream()
                .filter(condition)
                .map(TrimmedElement::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return new MyCustomArrayAdapter<TrimmedElement>(context, trimmedList);
    }
    
    static class WholeElement {}
    static class TrimmedElement {
        public TrimmedElement(WholeElement ele) {
            // Copy the information desired
        }
    }
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59095919)

Hope this helps.